# How can I move a file to an argument path?

Tags: linux, unix, opensuse

Say I had the following code,

```
mkdir $1
# Output that the folder was created and the name
echo "The folder was created and name is: `echo $1`"

touch $2
# Output that the file was created and the name
echo "The file was created and name is: `echo $2`"
```

How could I move the file that was created to the argument folder created ?

Comment: You really don't need the nested `echo` commands: `echo "The folder was created and name is: $1"`.  Also, at that stage, you have not verified that the folder was created; the `mkdir` might have failed but the script will still say "it was created".

Answer (score 2):

```
touch "$1/$2"
```

That assumes that `$2` is a simple name.  Or, if you must use `mv`, then:

```
touch "$2" &&
mv "$2" "$1"
```

Or:

```
touch "$2" &&
mv "$2" "$1/$2"
```

You might need to think about what would happen if `$2` is not a simple file name but contains some path information.  In that case, the first 'touch and move' combination is arguable safer.  Note that these versions check that the `touch` succeeds before moving the created file.  Also notice that `touch` works fine if the file already exists, and that file will be moved to the target directory.  If the file is not supposed to exist (yet), you have to work harder, again.  That's the trouble with these questions - there are many circumstances that might need to be dealt with, but probably don't for a homework question (but would have to be considered in something more nearly 'production code').

Otherwise, if `$2` could be a name with path information:

```
mkdir "$1" || exit 1
base=$(basename "$2")
touch "$1/$base" || exit 1
```

Or, if you want moving, then:

```
mkdir "$1" || exit 1
touch "$2" || exit 1
mv "$2" "$1"
```

Note the quotes around the file names; they will work even if the names contain spaces or other awkward characters.  Note, too, that if `$2` specifies a directory, the `mv` version of things will move the entire directory underneath the (newly created) `$1` directory.

Comment: That's clearly more efficient than creating an empty file and moving it, but since this is homework I think the OP is asking explicitly about `mv`.

Answer (score 2):

Your need to use the command `mv`

i.e. `mv $2 $1`

Answer (score 0):

Would `mv $2 $1` be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
mv $2 $1
echo "The file $2 was moved to $1"
```

Note that you don't need the second `echo` in each of  your commands:

```
echo "The folder was created and name is: $1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which commands can be used for copying or, in this case, moving the files that you created. Also, what's stopping you from creating the file directly in the created folder?